# Django 1.6.5 ImportError at / No module named stuffsite

Tags: django

[Django 1.6.5  ImportError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qKSv.jpg)

I was running my django project when i opened to the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/ this error shows .could assist me

Answer (score 1):

you possibly forgot to add the `stuffsite` app into INSTALLED_APPS and you are trying to import something from this app